# Moment-timezone .quarter() returning wrong year

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';


const datePassed = "2016-01-01";
const timeZone = "America/Los_Angeles";
const date = moment(datePassed, 'YYYY-MM-DD').tz(timeZone);
console.log("date.quarter() : ", date.quarter());
console.log("date.format(YY) : ", date.format('YY'));
```

I would expect the quarter to be 1 and year to be 16 but instead I get 4 and 15...

This is what prints

```
date.quarter() :  4
date).format(YY) :  15
```

I have printed the moment date object and looks like timezone is set and the date is encoded properly. I'm in the east coast so hence why I am trying to standarize it back to west coast time
[image]

Comment: what I'm guessing is that, since the time is automatically `00:00:00` you're localizing it to `2015-12-31` at some point in time

Comment: yep it's right there in your screen shot, `Thu Dec 31, 2015 16:00:00`

Comment: `moment.tz(..., String)` is used to create a moment with a time zone, and `moment().tz(String)` is used to change the time zone on an existing moment.  from [momentjs docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)